# Derivative of the log with respect to a parameter and equates to zero to find the estimate

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization

I tried to figure out how to to solve the following expression for the parameter $\theta$ using maximum likelihood method:

I solve the problem (very huge so I omitted it) and then got this:

$$ -\frac{1}{\theta+1} - \log(uv)
- \frac{1}{\theta^2} \log\left(u^{-\theta}+v^{-\theta}-1\right) - \left(2+\frac{1}{\theta}\right) \log\left(u^{-\theta}+v^{-\theta}-1\right) = 0$$

I would like to find the estimate of $\theta$

Any help please?

Comment: You might want to clean up your formula a bit so it's easier to read.  If you can't solve for theta analytically, then you can find *a* zero of your equation quickly using Newton's method.

Comment: This is the simplest formula. So, I cannot simplify it more than this.

Comment: What I mean is the formatting of the LaTeX is poorly done.

Comment: I really do not know how to use latex here, any help will be great.

Comment: Ok, so like I said I think your best bet if you can't solve it analytically is to use an iterative method like Newton's method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think also, we can leave it as it and solve it numerically.

Comment: Is this the first order condition for the maximum likelihood problem? It does not look like it will have an analytic solution to me. Probably your best bet is to solve the original maximum likelihood problem numerically.

Comment: This is the first order derivative with respect to $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Numerically, finding maxima (or minima) is generally easier than root finding, so your best bet is numerical optimization directly on the log likelihood function.